# remove <li> based on button click

Tags: jquery

How can I delete a list based on the button clicked?

```
<ul id="list"> 
  <li><input type ="button" name="Clear" value = "Clear1"/></li> 
  <li><input type ="button" name="Clear" value = "Clear2"/></li>
  <li><input type ="button" name="Clear" value = "Clear3"/></li>
</ul>
```

e.g If I click clear2, it must remove the list it belongs.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function() { 
   $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$('input[type="button"]')`, or `$('#list > li > input')`?

Comment: Why yes I do.  Thanks for the spot... my head was in my own project ;)

Comment: -1 For if the button is not under `li`, the parent of that button will still be removed and not a good idea... e.g. `div` with a `button`.

Comment: @Reigel - and yet... all the buttons *are* under li's.  You could easily change it to closest('li') or filter the result for 'li' - but I prefer to keep my answers straightforward and simple for obvious beginners.

Comment: @womp Yes, but I think you should be explaining it for beginners... `closest()` is still not the answer... you might want to `$("#list :button").click()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("input[type=button]").click(function()
  {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

**Note**: Using **Jquery** here.

Comment: Your initial posted solution does not work - you're including functions in a selector in a way that jQuery does not behave.

Comment: @Erik: please take your time to have a look at my answer again and respond accordintly, thanks.

Comment: Removed the -1 since you removed the incorrect answer. :) Also, you should avoid recommending that people put handlers inline. While not 'wrong' its bad practice.

Comment: @Erik: Thanks man, you are right, i should not post inline solutions but i wanted to be little quick :)

Comment: -1 For if the button is not under `li`, the parent of that button will still be removed and not a good idea... e.g. `div` with a button.

Comment: @Reigel: i don't undertand what you mean and why :(

Comment: Using this code, if there is another button on the form, it will work for any other button though it may not have to have the same function!!!

Comment: @user269431 You are correct, if the button happens to be in a form, and the form happens to be the parent, the form will be remove.

Comment: @user269431 and @Reigel: You can easily modfiy the code with closest, etc but this was made to be simple. Thanks

Comment: closest is still not the answer... you should be more clear on that to beginners... look for your code here http://jsbin.com/eciki

Answer (score 0):

this should be the accurate answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#list :button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

});​
```

for if you use suggestions of [womp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63756/womp)'s and [Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz)'s, you might be removing the wrong element.. You can see what I mean [here](http://jsbin.com/eciki).

Comment: if the list has an Id, how can we improve on the above code? In this case, the event will be launched on all anu list containing a button.

Comment: Also, I may have a button in the list that may have another event? The above example does not cater for a save button, that may create a list dynamically and add it as the last list.

Comment: hhmmm... you were not clear on that one... but if you can see, I already answered your question above.. How about clicking the check on the right, then ask another question on stackoverflow.